# Regex to check for 3 same letters in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create regex which will look for 3 same letters in a string, regardless of the order.

Example:

```
'aa2ff333' -> false
'aa2a' -> true
'aaa2' -> true
```

I tried this but it check for consecutive letters:

```
(.)\1\1
```

Any advice?

Comment: Sort them first and use your expression on the sorted string.

Comment: what if there are 4 letters?

Comment: Does it have to case sensitive ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this regex with lookahead:

```
/([a-zA-Z])(?=(?:.*?\1){2})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKyljc/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `([a-zA-Z])`: Match a letter `[a-zA-Z]` and capture it in group #1
- `(?=`: Start lookahead

  - `(?:.*?\1){2}`: That has at least 2 occurrences of same character as in capture group #1. `.*?\1` Matches back-reference `\1` after 0 or more of any character. This allows matching repetitions anywhere in input.
- `)`: End lookahead

Comment: Use: `/([a-z])(?=(?:.*?\1){2})/i` if you want to ignore case for repetitions of letters.

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice code sir. Could you please throw some light why negative look behind is needed here? Apologies if its a dummy question.

Comment: Actually this is a positive lookahead not a negative look behind. As mentioned in answer `(?=...)` is to make sure 2 more occurrences of same character as in capture group #1.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to loop through the string and count occurrence of each character then check if any of character appears for exact three times

```js
let threeChars = (str) => {
  let obj = [...str].reduce((op, inp) => {
    if (/[a-z]/i.test(inp)) {
      op[inp] = op[inp] || 0
      op[inp] += 1
    }
    return op
  }, {})
  return Object.values(obj).some(v => v === 3)
}


console.log(threeChars('aa2ff333'))
console.log(threeChars('aa2a'))
console.log(threeChars('aaa2'))
```

---

P.S:-

- You can make it case insensitive by removing the `i` flag
- In case you need to at least 3 character you can change `v == 3` to `v >= 3`